# How to add Google Analytics to Cocoa Touch Framework for iOS devices

Tags: ios, cocoa, google-analytics, cocoapods, ios-frameworks

I have created a framework which provides data from our APIs to our clients who use it.  I want to use Google Analytics in this framework.

But I am not able to figure out how to do it, there's no documentation or tutorial available for it, specifically of my requirement to use Google Analytics in framework.

Comment: Please provide more context: what have you tried? do you get any errors while trying?

Comment: It has been solved. I wanted to track usages of my framework using Google Analytics. But it was not working when I embedded my .framework file with the xcode project. But, it was conflicting with the existing Google Analytics of the project itself. Ultimately I solved it using Google Analytics Measurement Protocol, which is nothing but just simple HTTP requests to GA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using [Google Analytics Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/).

I wanted to track usages of my framework using Google Analytics. But it was not working when I embedded my .framework file with the xcode project. Because it was conflicting with the existing Google Analytics of the project itself.

Ultimately I solved it using Google Analytics Measurement Protocol, which is nothing but just simple HTTP requests to GA.

Here's My code for iOS using Swift 3 for sending Screen Name to GA -

```
let screen_payload = [
    "v": "app_version",                    // app_version
    "tid": "your_GA_tracking_id",          // tracking id
    "uid": "unique_user_id",               // app_id debug
    "an":"app_id_or_name",                 // app name
    "aid":"1.0.0",                         // app version id
    "t":"screenview",                      // type of GA analytic request
    "cd":"your_custom_screen_name"         // screen name
] as [String : Any]

// Request using Alamofire
Alamofire.request( "https://www.google-analytics.com/collect", method: .post, parameters: screen_payload).response{ response in
    print("\(String(describing: screen_payload))")
    print(response)
}
```

Here are some more useful links -

- https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/
- https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters